# How to find all elements with an attr in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this example but it specifically searches all inputs as opposed to all elements:

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

How can I update this example to search *all* elements in the DOM, not just inputs for those that contain a particular attribute like "myAttribute"?

Comment: atleast share your code

Comment: It selects all the inputs because you copied their example that looks at the inputs with the attribute :) Remove the element selector

Comment: You just leave out the tag selector: `$('[attributeName="foo"]')`

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all elements based on attributes by just taking the element tag name out of the selector in the example.

```
$( "input[value='Hot Fuzz']" )
```

Finds input elements with value="Hot Fuzz"

```
$( "[value='Hot Fuzz']" )
```

Finds any element with value="Hot Fuzz"

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the jQuery docs explain this somewhere, but when you select with jQuery you can select by tag, class, attribute, etc. and combine those in anyway you want. In your case, to select just an attribute, you would use:

```
$("[value='Hot Fuzz]");
```

This will select any element. The example you included was combining that with an element selector for input.